# Using 'make' command with GCC 7.2.0 on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang

I need to use the 'make' command on an application that requires GCC 4.8 or above. I have GCC 7.2.0 installed using Homebrew. Unfortunately when I use the 'make' command, it still seems to use CLANG and I get the following error:

> GCC >= 4.8 required! Your version is 4.2.1.  Stop.

I also set the first path in $PATH to the correct directory, i.e.

> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0

But I am still getting the same error. I've checked the gcc install using 'brew info gcc' and everything looks good:

> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.1.0 (1,486 files, 283.8MB)
>     Poured from bottle on 2017-05-29 at 19:37:24
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0 (1,487 files, 285.5MB) *
>     Built from source on 2017-12-23 at 19:09:14
>   From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gcc.rb
>   ==> Dependencies
>   Required: gmp ✔, libmpc ✔, mpfr ✔, isl ✔
>   ==> Options
>   --with-jit
>       Build just-in-time compiler
>   --with-nls
>       Build with native language support (localization)
>   --HEAD
>       Install HEAD version

What am I doing wrong? I have been searching online for the past several hours and every random solution has not fixed the problem.

Comment: **homebrew** will have installed at `/usr/local/bin/gcc-7`

Comment: `gcc` on Mac OS is usually synonymous with `clang`.  Can you edit your question to show the output of `/usr/local/bin/gcc --version` (I'm assuming brew installs under `/usr/local`).  It looks as if something somewhere is misinterpreting the output of `gcc --version`.

Comment: Try `make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-7`

Comment: @G.M. The path that I am using was based on 'brew info gcc'. There is a file under /usr/local/bin/ called 'gcc-7' and a 'g++-7'. Should I use that instead?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I get the exact same error when using that command instead of the simple 'make' command

Comment: Your PATH should normally start with `/usr/local/bin` if you use **homebrew**, rather than anything containng`Cellar`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I changed my path so that it does start with usr/local/bin. echo path gives: "usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin". The error is still there though. It keeps stating that I do not have the latest version of gcc.

Comment: **homebrew** has installed `/usr/localbin/gcc-7` not `gcc`. `gcc` is not `gcc-7`. If you run `type gcc` you will get `/usr/bin/gcc` and if you run `gcc -v` you will see that is the Apple-supplied `clang`. If you run `type gcc-7` you will get `/usr/local/bin/gcc-7` which is the **homebrew** one and which you can confirm by running `gcc -7`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162120/discussion-between-kimusubi-and-mark-setchell).